# Expected number of triangles with random lines

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Take the square $[0,1]^2$ and divide it up with $n$ random lines. We can choose our random lines by choosing one point randomly on one of the four sides and then choosing another point randomly lines and also what is the probability that no region is greater than $0.5$?

If anyone has any cases or any ideas, or especially a full solution I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!